# checkbox val not showing false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the follwoing code:

```
 $("input:checkbox").live('click', function() {
                          alert($(this).val());
});
```

True is shown if the checkbox is checked.  However, if the checkbox is checked and I uncheck it, the value shown is still true.  How can I correct that?  What is wrong with the code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a checkbox is always the same. You need to see if it is checked or not.

```
….attr('checked');
```

Comment: +1 - Also there's `this.checked` (fastest) or `.is(':checked')` :)

Comment: Oh no, I've fallen into the "They are writing it in jQuery. Must use jQuery no matter how inefficient it is" trap!

Answer (score 1):

```
this.checked //true/false - not jquery
$(element).checked //does not work
$(element).attr('checked') //checked/NULL *
$(element).is(':checked') //true/false
```

***note** that `<input TYPE=CHECKBOX CHECKED=CHECKED>` returns in both checked/unchecked state `checked`