# How can I pass unchecked checkbox to cookie in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, checkbox

I can pass the checked value just fine.  But when I uncheck it, the value is null and doesn't overwrite the cookie.  What do you recommend?

```
$("input[name=box]").change(function(e) {
    $.cookie("autoplay", $(e.target).val());
    window.location.reload();
});
```

and the html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1">
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
$.cookie("autoplay", this.checked);
```

I just used this to track true or false.

Comment: When the checkbox is unchecked, what should be written to the cookie? `'null'` or `0`, or ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operator to catch all falsy values :

```
$(e.target).val() ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.checked` is fastest if the value isn't necessary.  As [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881642/checkbox-val-not-showing-false).